# jQuery Validate set rule using wildcard to find target fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Is there possibility to add rules by wildcard?  I think it's not possible to set rules like this...

```
$("#form").validate({
        // errorLabelContainer: $("div#error"),
        errorElement: "p",
        errorClass: "form-error",
        rules: {
             $("input[name*='x.child']"): {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Could you discuss what you think that wildcard is going to accomplish? That will help users steer you in the right direction. I could understand if you have the wildcard on the right side what your intention was, but left side leaves me with a puzzled look

Comment: I have multiple input and select tags on my page, all are with names like this "x.child.1.0.t", "x.child.2.0.t", "x.child.3.0.t" (starting with x.child), so i need to add required rule for all of them :)

Comment: Why not give them a class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the built-in `rules()` method to add rules.  [See documentation.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules)

Note:  You **must** call this method *after* you call `.validate()`.

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kSFKE/2/)

```
$("#form").validate({
    errorElement: "p",
    errorClass: "form-error"
});

// the following method must come AFTER .validate()
$("input[name*='x.child']").each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
    });
});
```

This method can also be very useful when you are dynamically adding fields to your form.

The following to combine with custom `messages:`.  Note that the format is slightly different than when adding rules as options within `.validate()`...

```
$("input[name*='x.child']").each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        messages: {
            required: "Required input",
            minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters are necessary")
        }
    });
});
```

---

As mentioned elsewhere, you can also create a `class` and use like this...

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kSFKE/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="myclass" name="whatever" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#form").validate({
    errorElement: "p",
    errorClass: "form-error"
});

// the following method must come AFTER .validate()
$('#form').find('.myclass').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        messages: {
            required: "Required input",
            minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters are necessary")
        }
    });
});
```