# How to use wildcards with jQuery Validation Plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can I validate forms with jQuery plugin with ids that have a name pattern, like #formNewHouse1, #formNewHouse2,.. ?

This code is working with a single type (normal) form:

```
$("#formNewHouse").validate({
    rules: {
        formNewHouseName: {
            required: true
        },
        formNewHouseAddress: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        formNewHouseName: {
            required: "Please type a name"
        },
        formNewHouseAddress: {
            required: "Please type an address"
        }
    }
});
```

I need something like this, where X = 2,3,6,18,19,... (IDs from DB) how can I achieve this?

```
$("#formNewHouseX").validate({
    rules: {
        formNewHouseNameX: {
            required: true
        },
        formNewHouseAddressX: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        formNewHouseNameX: {
            required: "Please type a name"
        },
        formNewHouseAddressX: {
            required: "Please type an address"
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solution: learn how to use class names.

Comment: @shmiddty The problem isn't having to attache `.validate()` to each unique ID (which yes, he could do with the same class name). It's that he appears to have also named the fields in each form with that number, which need to be individually called out in the validation plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, similar to this question with a working answer:

[jQuery Validate set rule using wildcard to find target fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13885056/594235)

---

Here's an answer along with something the others are lacking... [a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anUXf/1/):

Use jQuery's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method to initialize `.validate()` on all matching forms.

Then use the built-in `rules()` method to add rules and assign them by `class`.  [See documentation.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules)

**HTML:**

```
<form id="formNewHouse1">
    <input type="text" class="myclass" name="formNewHouseName" />
    <input type="text" class="myclass" name="formNewHouseAddress" />
</form>

<form id="formNewHouse2">
    <input type="text" class="myclass" name="formNewHouseName2" />
    <input type="text" class="myclass" name="formNewHouseAddress2" />
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var myoptions = {
    // contains options for all forms
};

$("form[id^=formNewHouse]").each(function() {
    $(this).validate(myoptions);
});

// the following method must come AFTER .validate()
$('form').find('.myclass').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        digits: true, // just another example rule
        messages: {
            required: "Required input",
            digits: "Please only enter digits"
        }
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/anUXf/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle and answer, this worked correctly with every input :)

Comment: BTW. If anyone needs to set different error messages, just use different class names (As I did):
    $('form').find('.myclassForName').each(function() {...});
    $('form').find('.myclassForAddress').each(function() {...});

Comment: @DuckN'Bear, yes, just use a custom `class` for each rule **or** for each _set_ of rules.  Glad you got the idea and it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

First, validate all your forms with one call. Last I checked, jQuery Validate didn't correctly handle validating a collection, so you'll need to use `.each` (or similar) to create a new validator for each form.

```
$("form[id^=formNewHouse]").each(function() { $(this).validate() });
```

Then, add classes to your fields so you can select them en masse and apply the rules.

```
$('.newHouseName').rules('add', {required: true, messages: {required: 'Please type a name'}});
$('.newHouseAddress').rules('add', {required: true, messages: {required: 'Please type an address'}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better of using classes but if you need to use ids you can use something like this

```
$("form[id^='formNewHouse']").validate({
    //...
});
```

This will select all the form elements that have the id that starts with 'formNewHouse'

Comment: Dear Reader:  this answer is no good, broken, incorrect.  See [demo constructed by @politus](http://jsfiddle.net/Qx7g6/) and act accordingly.  @DuckN'Bear, please do not "accept" an answer until you are sure it's working properly.

Comment: I agree, I see now that this is not working, you should go with @Mathletics solution!!!

Comment: Or go with my solution which contains a working demo.  Meanwhile @DZL, are you allowed to delete this answer?

Comment: Sorry everybody, answer from @DZL seemed to work, but after some further tests I noticed it only works on the first form, not in the rest. So yes, this is not the right answer, I will try the other answer and accept correctly. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is how you've structured your page. I assume you have something like

```
<form id="formNewHouse1">
    <input type="text" name="newHouseName1" />
    <input type="text" name="newHouseAddress1" />
</form>

<form id="formNewHouse2">
    <input type="text" name="newHouseName2" />
    <input type="text" name="newHouseAddress2" />
</form>
```

Which leads to the problem you're having with calling out each individual input to give rules for validation. But I think if you restructure your HTML, you can clean everything up nicely. You can just give your forms unique names/ids but keep the inputs named the same thing.

```
<form id="formNewHouse1" class="formNewHouse">
    <input type="text" name="newHouseName" />
    <input type="text" name="newHouseAddress" />
</form>

<form id="formNewHouse2"  class="formNewHouse">
    <input type="text" name="newHouseName" />
    <input type="text" name="newHouseAddress" />
</form>
```

Then you can call your validation like you had in your post, but using a class instead.:

```
$(".formNewHouse").validate({
    rules: {
        formNewHouseName: {
            required: true
        },
        formNewHouseAddress: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        formNewHouseName: {
            required: "Please type a name"
        },
        formNewHouseAddress: {
            required: "Please type an address"
        }
    }
});
```

If you're dynamically generating your input names though, then you're putting yourself in the position where you need to do them all separately. So I hope that's not what you're doing.