# Pass rules to class with jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validate Plugin that is available on the official jQuery website to validade my forms. Everything was going just fine until I have to pass rules, not based on a field `name`, but on `class` or `id`.  I can't manage to do that.

This an example of how I am passing rules to the field with `name="comment"`.

This is my jQuery code

```
$("#comForm").validate({
    rules: {
        comment: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 500
        }
    }
});
```

This is my form

```
  <form id="comForm" action="#" method="post" >
  <textarea rows="4" name="comment" placeholder="What do you think?" class="input-xxlarge" id="defaultform"></textarea></br>
  <textarea rows="4" name="othercomment" placeholder="What do you think?" class="input-xxlarge" id="defaultform"></textarea></br>
  <input type="submit" value="Rate!" class="btn btn-primary">
  </form>
```

Let's just say I want to pass the rules to every field with the default form `id` or to all fields with `input-xxlarge` `class`. Is that possible?

Comment: You cannot have elements with duplicate `id`s. You'll run into all kinds of trouble--use classes instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but you really should not use duplicate `id`'s... it's invalid HTML and it will lead to JavaScript issues.  Use `class` if you need duplicates.

Use the built-in `rules()` method to add rules and assign them by `class`.  [See documentation.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules)

Then use jQuery's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method to to apply rules to all matching elements using that same `class`.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">
    <textarea class="myclass" name="field1" ></textarea>
    <textarea class="myclass" name="field2" ></textarea>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // your other rules and options
});

// the following method must come AFTER .validate()
$('.myclass').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 500,
        messages: {
            required: "Required input",
            minlength: "Must be at least {0} characters",
            maxlength: "Must be less than {0} characters"
        }
    });
});
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4ujFS/)**

---

Also, similar to this question:

[jQuery Validate set rule using wildcard to find target fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13885056/594235)

Comment: Thanks this was very helpfull, the only problem is that, when an error occurs the jquery always add the error class on the first .myclass, any idea on how to change that?

Comment: @André, [See my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ujFS/).  The error is properly added to _both_ fields.  You must use `.each()`.

Comment: I really dont know whats happening, this is what a did http://pastebin.com/0xGEy8Jh  looks good on paper!

Comment: @André, Can't see your HTML in that pastebin.  But as you can see here, it really works:  http://jsfiddle.net/4ujFS/

Comment: I think i know what is going on, iam using the same id, on every field, this must be the problem, gonna try to fix that and see whats happen. Thanks alot, for all your support and help!

Comment: @André, Yes... as stated before, you can **NOT** use duplicate `id`'s... it's invalid HTML and this is how it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard jquery selectors to add rules to elements like this:

```
$(".required").rules("add", { 
  required:true,  
  minlength:1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply rules trough data-rule attributes. This is the easiest way and possibly the best way to maintain a clean code...

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="email" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-email="true">
<input type="text" name="password" id="passoword" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-minlength="6">
<input type="text" name="password-confirm" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-minlength="6" data-rule-equalsto="#password">
```

you can even provide messages trough data attribures:

```
<input id="cemail" name="email" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-email="true" data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address" />
```

In JavaScript just call:

```
$('#myform').validate();
```